# Need help identifying a 4 pin SMD component of a blood pressure monitor

Tags: identification, components

I have a blood pressure monitor that got damaged by a higher voltage than its working voltage.

I saw these components have totally exploded and found a similar device to get this picture.

I don't know what that "A" means on the circuit. Which component symbol is "A", and what is this component?

I've tried searching for SMD codes with SP but found nothing like this.

[image: this smd]
[image: around it]

Comment: It would help to see more of the context around this component.

Comment: I’d love to know what package that is - it looks like a 4 pin sot 23, which I don’t think exists.

Comment: I will try to find more of its around

Comment: Its package is like sot143, sot23 has 3pin

Comment: It looks like the Microchip logo to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a SOT-143 package.
After a quick search of this package with the SP label I got some ESD protection devices, for example [this](https://www.newark.com/littelfuse/sp0503bahtg/diode-tvs-30pf-sot-143/dp/92K8959) one.

Comment: This is clearly not SOT-143 since all pads are of the same size.

Comment: From my point of view, pad 3 is bigger than the others. As I do not have access to the real board I cannot be of course confident on this.

Comment: Look at the second picture. SOT-143 also has a larger body, I believe.

Comment: i think its sot143 too, but I had figured out that the A on its circuit is stand for IC as the main micro-controller is A1

Comment: Pin 1 seems to be GND and Pin 3 Vcc, try to measure this hypothesis if you can.
I would try to connect an oscilloscope to see what's going on.

Comment: I got this picture from another device that i saw somewhere else :(

Comment: The symbol in the first image looks to me like the m of the "microchip technology" brand.
Nevertheless, the components that I found doesn't seem to make sense in that place.